# Netfilter hook is not called in Ubuntu 18.04 - kernel 4.18

Tags: ubuntu, hook, icmp, netfilter

I am trying to create a netfilter hook which simply catches ICMP packets. I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong (I am new to writing kernel modules). The code i have so far is

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>

#define DIP "1.2.3.4"

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;
static struct net n;

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Monitor packets");
MODULE_AUTHOR("john");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

unsigned int hook_func(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "hook!\n");
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module()
{
    int ret;
    nfho.hook = hook_func;
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; 
    nfho.pf = AF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    ret = nf_register_net_hook(&n, &nfho);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "module is NOT loaded into the kernel\n");    
        return -1;    
    }
    else
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "module IS loaded into the kernel\n");      
        return 0;  
    }
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    nf_unregister_net_hook(&n, &nfho);
    printk(KERN_INFO "module has been unloaded\n");  
}
```

From my syslog it looks like the kernel module is loaded / unloaded correctly (from the print messages). I dont receive the "hook!" message when I ping my machine. Is it the wrong pf? the wrong hook priority? Can I debug this somehow?

It should be said that I'm in a virtual machine and that I'm pinging the VM from another physical machine which is not the host machine. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, result of "uname -a": Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-20-generic #21~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 8 08:43:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I know there is some unused includes. This is adapted from a code sample for another kernel version, which I plan to fill in later. I really hope someone can give me an idea of where to start looking or maybe see what I am doing wrong.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that are missing LKM entry/exit points:

```
module_init(init_module)  //for insmod
module_exit(cleanup_module) //for rmmod
```